# Why does this cause a deadlock in Go?

Tags: go, deadlock

This is not a question about how to better write this. It's a question specifically about why Go is causing a deadlock in this scenario.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    chan1 := make(chan bool)
    chan2 := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            <-chan1
            fmt.Printf("chan1\n")
            chan2 <- true
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            <-chan2
            fmt.Printf("chan2\n")
            chan1 <- true
        }
    }()

    for {
        chan1 <- true
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
chan1
chan2
chan1
chan2
chan1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
goroutine 5 [chan send]:
goroutine 6 [chan send]:
exit status 2
```

Why does this not cause an infinite loop? How come it does two full "ping-pings" (instead of just one) before giving up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the runtime perspective you get a deadlock because all routines try to send onto a channel and there's no routine waiting to receive anything.

But *why* is it happening? I will give you a story as I like visualising what my routines are doing when I encounter a deadlock.

You have two players (routines) and one ball (`true` value). Every player waits for a ball and once they get it they pass it back to the other player (through a channel). This is what your *two* routines are really doing and this would indeed produce an infinite loop.

The problem is the third player introduced in your main loop. He's hiding behind the second player and once he sees the first player has empty hands, he throws *another* ball at him. So we end up with both players holding a ball, couldn't pass it to another player because the other one has (the first) ball in his hands already. The hidden, evil player is also trying to pass *yet another* ball. Everyone is confused, because there're three balls, three players and no empty hands.

In other words, you have introduced the third player who is breaking the game. He should be an arbiter passing the very first ball at the beginning of the game, watching it, but stop producing balls! It means, instead of having a loop in you main routine, there should be simply `chan1 <- true` (and some condition to wait, so we don't exit the program).

If you enable logging in the loop of main routine, you will see the deadlock occurs *always* on the third iteration. The number of times the other routines are executed depends on the scheduler. Bringing back the story: first iteration is a kick-off of the first ball; next iteration is a mysterious second ball, but this can be handled. The third iteration is a deadlock – it brings to life the third ball which can't be handled by anybody.

Answer (score 1):

```
goroutine 1 [chan send]:
goroutine 5 [chan send]:
goroutine 6 [chan send]:
```

This tells it all: all your goroutines are blocked trying to send on a channel with no one to receive on the other end.

So your first goroutine blocks on  `chan2 <- true`, your second blocks on `chan1 <- true` and your main goroutine blocks on its own `chan1 <- true`.

As to why it does two "full ping-pings" like you say, it depends on scheduling and from which sender `<-chan1` decides to receive first.

On my computer, I get more and it varies each time I run it:

```
chan1
chan2
chan1
chan2
chan1
chan2
chan1
chan2
chan1
chan2
chan1
chan2
chan1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Comment: That is helpful and makes sense. So I'm going to assume that theres no way the channel can have more than one value added to it - so that means that Go has already deemed a goroutine as "asleep" rather than just simply blocked by the channel. How/why would it be asleep?

Comment: It is blocked by the channels operations, in a way that cannot unblock. The runtime detects that all goroutines are in a blocked state, so there is no event that could happen unblocking any of them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks complicated but the answer is easy.

It'll deadlock when:

- First routine is trying to write to `chan2`
- Second route is trying to write to `chan1`.
- Main is trying to write to `chan1`.

How can that happen? Example:

- Main writes `chan1`. Blocks on another write.
- Routine 1: `chan1` receives from Main. Prints. Blocks on write `chan2`.
- Routine 2: `chan2` receives. Prints. Blocks on write `chan1`.
- Routine 1: `chan1` receives from Routine 2. Prints. Blocks on write `chan2`.
- Routine 2: `chan2` receives. Prints. Blocks on write `chan1`.
- Main writes `chan1`. Blocks on another write.
- Routine 1: `chan1` receives from Main. Prints. Blocks on write `chan2`.
- Main writes `chan1`. Blocks on another write.

Currently all routines are blocked. i.e.:

Routine 1 cannot write to `chan2` because Routine 2 is not receiving but is actually blocked trying to write to `chan1`. But no one is listening on `chan1`.

As @HectorJ said, it all depends on the scheduler. But in this setup, a deadlock is inevitable.